# Cursor doesn´t give any answer

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to make a SQLite-DB an the function to grab the information of one entry doesn't give any answer. (So just to mention it, i'm a newbie)

```
public Infopw getInfo(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS+" WHERE " + 
           COLUMN_ID + " = "+id+";";
    Infopw in = new Infopw();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        String s = "w";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            s =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVER));
        }
        cursor.close();

        Log.d(TAG ,s);
    }

    return in;
}
```

This is my Code but it just doesn't do anything and the Log-Message does print out the "w" and not the `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVER));` I tried doing the 2 if-conditions in one but that is the same result.

Comment: There can be mistake in query, column name, parameter etc. verify all.

Comment: If your app does not crash, this means that the id you are passing to `getInfo()` does not exist in the table.

Comment: Put log inside of if-condition where You move cursor to first. There is a chance You get nothing and there is nothing to select.

Comment: If Your project is not strict private, You can share it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the last semicolon in the rawQuery.

You should use the cursor object in the following fashion.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    String s = "w";
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { //use while and not if, to get all the rows
        s =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVER));
    }
    //cursor.close();   Don't close it when the data is still being fetched

    Log.d(TAG ,s);
}
cursor.close(); //You can close it now after data is fetched
```

Comment: The semi-colon is not an issue. The only reason it is stated that it shouldn't be coded is because only single queries can be handled and therefor it is not needed. Additionally checking for a null Cursor returned from an SQLiteDatabase method that returns a Cursor is useless. The returned Cursor will not be null, it will be a valid instantiated Cursor object. If a Cursor cannot be created then an exception will result.